# Microphone get sound method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to call the delegate method when iphone microphone receive some sound. call a recorder delegate not called. i want to get the sound intensity.

I have tried this code. but not work.

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];



    [recorder record];

    [recorder updateMeters];
    level = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];



    [recorder stop];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

// This method called when user get a sound.......

```
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{


    NSLog(@"Sound level is  %f",level);

}
```

how may i do this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your recorder starts and stops at the same time , that is the reason why its delegate never fires. If I understood correctly what you want , then here is the solution.

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];



//[recorder record];  // Do not start recording here

[recorder updateMeters];
level = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
  self.meterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateAudioMeter)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
 }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
```

Get your metering levels here

```
  -(void)updateAudioMeter
    {
     [self.recorder updateMeters];
      self.dBLevel = [self.recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];

       if(self.dBLevel>-25)
         {
           [self.recorder record];
        }
        else 
          { 
             [self.recorder stop];
          } 
  }
```

Comment: i want to call the delegate method when microphone get some sound like clap near microphone.

Comment: Yes , I got that . Its the same solution. updateAudioMeter will check for sound levels and if it increased above ur given threshold vaule which is -25 here , recorder will start recording. You can add an upper value and lower value for starting and stoping the recorder

Comment: When user clap near microphone then recording will start, it is for that purpose only